# Effiiciently remove row from pandas dataframe with NaN in array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe where columns labeled e, f, and g contain numpy arrays corresponding to RGB values.

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 62 | 0 | [89, 86, 78] | [178, 171, 163] | [63, 58, 50] |
| 1 | 0 | 68 | 0 | [99, 94, 74] | [121, 113, 88] | [113, 108, 79] |
| 2 | 0 | 68 | 1 | [63, 7, 7] | [14, 9, 7] | [56, 42, 26] |

Some of the arrays however contain NaN values as part of their composition and I would like to remove the rows that contain them. I have a routine that does exactly this but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to accomplish it.

The code below does what I want but I was wondering if there is a faster/better/cleaner solution.

```
row,col = df.shape
for r in range(row):
   rv = df['e'][r][0]
   if type(rv) != np.uint32:
       df = df.drop(r)
```

I tried implementing variations of the `isnull` and `isna` methods but haven't been successful yet. I think that the issue may be due to the fact that I have arrays as the data elements.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `applymap`

```
df = df[~df.applymap(lambda x : np.isnan(x).any()).any(1)]
```